# Import CSV to postgresql (Zend/PHP)

Tags: php, postgresql, zend-framework, postgresql-9.1

I want to load test data into a table in my postgresql database.

I am doing this inside my unit test class.

```
$this->Application_Model_UserMapper->getDbTable()->getAdapter()->query("COPY users FROM '" . APPLICATION_PATH . "/../tests/dbtestdata/users.csv' CSV HEADER NULL AS E'\N'");
```

and I get an error message that says I must be a super user to copy to and from a file. Does that mean I need to log in as postgres user? I have read that that could cause security issues, so I am not keen on doing that.

Other option seems to be \COPY, but the following doesnt work..

```
$this->Application_Model_UserMapper->getDbTable()->getAdapter()->query("

  \COPY users FROM '" . APPLICATION_PATH . "/../tests/dbtestdata/users.csv' 
  CSV HEADER NULL AS E'\N'

");
```

I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\copy is used by psql, a PostgreSQL client. The SQL statement COPY is done by the user Postgres, your code needs this user or a different solution.

I really like [pg_put_line](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-put-line.php), then you can read the file in PHP and stream it to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I have almost made it work using the code here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-put-line.php but for some reason, COPY is not recognizing my column and row delimiters (\t and \n respectively). I solved the column delimiter issue by changing it to '|', but I am unable to provide more than 1 row of data. Would you have any suggestions?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/srwFLdut
It is not recognizing the \n so i cannot insert more than 1 line.

Comment: I fixed it by replacing the \n with an actual enter key. Any idea why this would happen? Is it because I am using a mac?